# Create file in a thread-safe manner

Tags: php, thread-safety, locking, file-locking

I have an array of filenames and each process need to create and write only to a single file.

This is what I came to:

```
foreach ($filenames as $VMidFile) {
    if (file_exists($VMidFile)) { // A
        continue;
    }

    $fp = fopen($VMidFile, 'c'); // B

    if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) { // C
        continue;
    }

    if (!filesize($VMidFile)) { // D
        // write to the file;

        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);
        break;
    }

    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp); // E
}
```

But I don't like that I'm relying on the `filesize`.

Any proposals to do it in another (better) way?

**UPD**: added the labels to discuss easily

**UPD 2**: I'm using `filesize` because I don't see any other reliable way to check if the *current* thread created the file (thus it's empty yet)

**UPD 3**: the solution **should be** condition race free.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @Mathew Foscarini: it's managing of 3rd party resources that don't have concurrency synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible, slightly ugly solution would be to lock on a lock file and then testing if the file exists:

```
$lock = fopen("/tmp/".$filename."LOCK", "w"); // A

if (!flock($lock, LOCK_EX)) { // B
    continue;
}
if(!file_exists($filename)){ // C
    //File doesn't exist so we know that this thread will create it
    //Do stuff to $filename
    flock($lock, LOCK_UN); // D
    fclose($lock);
}else{
    //File exists. This thread didn't create it (at least in this iteration).
    flock($lock, LOCK_UN);
    fclose($lock);
}
```

This should allow exclusive access to the file and also allows deciding whether the call to `fopen($VMidFile, 'c');` will create the file.

Comment: Yep, this could work (synchronization files for synchronization files - "we need to go deeper") ;-) +1

Comment: but can't this leak a lock if it crashes in critical section o.O

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating a file and hoping that it's not interfered with:

1. create a *temporary* file
2. do all necessary file operations on it
3. [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) it to the new location if location doesn't exist.

Technically, since `rename` will overwrite the destination there is a chance that concurrent threads will still clash. That's very unlikely if you have:

```
if(!file_exists($lcoation) { rename(...
```

You could use [`md5_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) to verify the file contents is correct after this block.

Comment: "rename it to the new location if location doesn't exist." --- how would you check it in a thread-safe manner? "there is a chance" -- I don't want to rely on "chance". "That's very unlikely" --- I don't want to rely on "likely or not", I want the solution that **guarantees** that it will always work as expected.

Comment: So do you have a proposal that is free of condition race? Now it's not an answer, sorry.

Comment: I like this proposal; it makes the critical section tiny.

Answer (score 1):

You can secure exclusive access using [semaphores](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.sem.php) (UNIX only, and provided the `sysvsem` extension is installed):

```
$s = sem_get(ftok($filename), 'foo');
sem_acquire($s);

// Do some critical work...

sem_release($s);
```

Otherwise you can also use [`flock`](http://php.net/flock). It does not require any special extensions, but according to [comments on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sem-acquire.php#107292) is a bit slower than using semaphores:

```
$a = fopen($file, 'w');
flock($a, LOCK_EX);

// Critical stuff, again

flock($a, LOCK_UN);
```

Comment: If you check my question you'll see, that I'm already using `flock`

Comment: they will lead to the same question - how to check if the file was created by the current process. Not sure I understand how I can synchronize `file_exists` with semaphore

Comment: I'd first acquire a semaphore, and then -- when exclusive access is already ensured -- check whether the file exists; if not, the current thread/process will definitely create it.

Comment: it's blocking solution. Indeed it will work, but it blocks everything

Answer (score 0):

Use mode 'x' instead of 'c' in your fopen call. And check the resulting $fp, if it's false, the file wasn't created by the current thread, and you should continue to the next filename.

Also, depending your PHP's installation settings, you may want to put an @ in front of the fopen call to suppress any warnings if fopen($VMidFile, 'x') is unable to create the file because it already existed.

This should work even without flock.

Comment: What if a script dies and doesn't clean up the file? It would require a human interaction to clean the file to run again, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not sure how this relates to the original problem, what do you mean 'clean up the file'? Delete it afterwards, or..? It can be taken care of automatically, as long as you can define the exact conditions that determine whether another thread may still be running and working on the file, or if it crashed and the file has become orphaned.

Comment: so that's the original question: "as long as you can define the exact conditions that determine whether another thread may still be running" --- that's what I asked about a locking mechanism for. And the mechanism should be reliable so that it didn't require any additional heuristics. With your proposal I see that the algorithm will be in stuck if a process dies and doesn't remove the file.

Comment: Well the 'x' mode takes care of all the thread-safety and race conditions, it's basically a lock mechanism by itself. When or where would it get stuck, exactly?

Comment: the process dies and the file is left there. No process could be run again due to `x` will never "obtain a lock"

Comment: To avoid partially processed files, you may want to introduce a 'thread status' or something, where each thread frequently updates if it's still working on some file, or successfully finished it. Then other threads can check if a particular file is still being worked on, and if it has been for more than a long amount of time, consider the thread dead and reprocess the file. But this is a different problem than the thread-exclusive creation of a new file.

Comment: So what is the reason to use this proposal which requires another mechanisms to maintain keepalive state and wait for keepalive to expire in case if a process dies? While the other solutions are free of these issues "But this is a different problem than the thread-exclusive creation of a new file" --- the original problem wasn't about a TS creation of a new file, it was about a TS processing of something.

Comment: The initial post was all about creating a file in a thread-safe manner, which you pulled off with locks and filesize check. I guess that works, but I think the 'x' mode is a simpler and better alternative. Yet neither solution takes care of reprocessing files that got orphaned from died threads (the filesize check doesn't either, a thread may have died half way writing the file).

Comment: By the way, as far as I can see, none of the other solutions are free of these issues?

Comment: The checked is, isn't it?

Comment: No, how does that deal with (or even just detect) if some thread died prematurely, halfway writing the file? As opposed to some thread still working on it?